# Google Maps Storelocator with filter (attributes)

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

i am using this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?hl=de

Everything works so far, but how can i add a function to filter within the results by attributes? 
Anyone here who has something for me? I can not find anything so far.

many Thanks!

Comment: filter attributes in the marker table?

Comment: I want to filter the categories after getting the result list. So the user can swith between "attribute A,B or C".

Answer (score 0):

Create a selectbox with id "cat": `<select id="cat">`

add the selected value of this select to `searchUrl` in `function searchLocationsNear`:

```
 var e = document.getElementById("cat");
 var cat = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

 var searchUrl = 'phpsqlajax_search.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() +   '&radius=' + radius;
 searchurl += '&cat=' + cat;
```

add your filter to the query in phpsqlsearch_genxml.php:

```
// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers  WHERE `category`='%s' HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string(empty($_GET['cat'])?'':$_GET['cat']))
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius);
$result = mysql_query($query);
```